# Javascript using Phonegap Global Arrays not Working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am creating a phonegap app to fetch contacts and save them in the database. I have created two empty global arrays at the top that will save the phone number and display name of a person which will be later stored in a database table. To check that the contacts are successfully saved in the array, I have created a `test_data()` function.

Now my problem is that the `test_data()` code is not working and no values are displayed in the log. Now if I move that code from `test_data()` function to `onSuccess()` it works fine. Here is the code. Isn't it the proper way to declare global a array in JS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Contact Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
     var gcont = []; var gphon = [];

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {

    // find all contacts with 'Bob' in any name field
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter=""; 
    options.multiple=true;
    var fields = ["displayName", "phoneNumbers"];
    navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
    test_data();
    }

    // onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts
    //
    function onSuccess(contacts) {


    for(var index=0;index<contacts.length;index++){ 
    gcont[index] = contacts[index].displayName; 
    gphon[index] = contacts[index].phoneNumbers[0].value; 

    }           


    }

    function test_data(){
    for (z=0;z<gcont.length;z++){
    console.log(gcont[z]);}
 }




    // onError: Failed to get the contacts
    //
    function onError(contactError) {
        alert('Error With Contacts!');
    }


    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Find Contacts</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to test_data() doesn't work in onDeviceReady() because the onSuccess callback to contacts.find is asynchronous and the arrays have not been populated when test_data() is executed.

Comment: Can you tell me more about asynchronous functions as my JS knowledge is pretty basic or can you tell me whats wrong with the above code, how can i fix it ?

Comment: You answered this question yourself, if you want to do anything with the result of contacts.find it needs to be in onSuccess function.